# JQuery: Grid plugin with filterable columns?

Tags: jquery, datagrid, data-visualization

Does anyone know of a jQuery grid plugin with filterable columns?

Obviously there are lots of jQuery grid plugins out there, and [discussions of the best ones on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations), but I can't find one with filterable columns.

Here's an example of what I mean by filterable columns: see [this page on The Guardian](http://www.guardian.co.uk/politics/government-spending-data/search?q=capita&order=desc&page=1&fq=&fq=&fq=&fq=&fq=Department-Family:%22Ministry+of+Defence%22&fq=).

Note how at the top of each column there is a **drop-down with a list of the possible filters**, and **counts by each one**.

This gives you an immediate sense of the filters available and the relative importance of each one.

[SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) looks exciting, and appears to support some filtering - [see this example](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html) - but it's not quite what I'm looking for. The filtering example asks you to enter a term in the title, but with 50,000 rows it's too difficult to know which titles are available, or whether one title is 100 times more common than another - so it's not an intuitive way to explore data you don't know well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=5) and expecially at its FilterToolbar sample (you will find a sample under "New in version 3.3" named "Multiple Toolbar Search" on the [Demo](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) page)

Here is the [wiki page](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods). Please look for `filterToolbar` mehod.

It is exactly as in your sample.

Comment: It's nice, but not quite as in the sample, alas - the sample shows all the possible options, and counts next to them. That's really useful for exploring the data, and that's what I'm looking for. So thanks for your answer, but I'm leaving the question open for now (and editing it so it's a bit clearer).

Comment: Ok, no problem for me. What do you mean by `the sample shows all the possible options`? If you refer to having a dropdown dropdown to filter data that could be done even on jqGrid. I have seen a sample somewhere, if I remember where I will post it here.

Comment: Yes - a dropdown with the possible options is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @AP257: In the sample that I've posted there's already a dropdown with some values in it. It filter the column Tax. You can have a look at the code for details...

Answer (score 1):

The best filtering table is [Watable](http://wootapa-watable.appspot.com/). I haven't found any other plugin which does number filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Check ShieldUI's [Filtering](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/filtering) and [Search by Filtering](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/search-by-filtering) demos - this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with grids and jQuery in a number of projects and we've always ended up using jqGrid. It can be a complex beast to master, and documentation can be tricky to sniff out, if you (and we always end up doing this) stray too far off reservation but it is powerful.